# Регулярка в R для удаления одиночных букв из текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Столкнулся со странной реакцией регулярок в R : некоторые буквы кириллицы R считает пунктуацией и начинает работать неадекватно.
Вопрос: как побороть эту странность для удаления одиночных букв из текста?
Код ниже показывает данную проблему:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\b[:alpha:]{1}\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж з  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)
gsub(pattern = "\\b[a-zа-ячё]{1}\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж з  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)
```

Comment: А  в чем конкретно проблема? `[:alpha:]` нужно писать как `[[:alpha:]]`. Вторую регулярку можно записать и как `"\\b[a-zа-яё]\\b"` (`ч` уже включен в диапазон `а-я`).

Comment: А вот это работает как надо - https://ideone.com/mLLtRi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более универсальное решение:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(" - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123",
                       "\\b\\p{L}\\b", " ")
#R> [1] " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж      ZZ 123"
```

Подробнее о регулярных выражениях в ICU: http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp.

См. также:

```
help("stringi-search-charclass", "stringi")
help("stringi-search-regex", "stringi")
```

Comment: При моих настройках (см.мой коммент выше), Ваш совет работает: буквы "Ч" и "Ё" считает как буквы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

В коде есть одна ошибка и 2 недочёта:

- `[:alpha:]` - символьные классы POSIX необходимо использовать внутри квадратных скобок ("скобочных выражений") (= `[[:alpha:]]`)
- `{1}` всегда можно и лучше удалять
- `ч` уже включен в диапазон `а-я`

Используйте

```
gsub(pattern = "\\b[[:alpha:]]\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)
gsub(pattern = "\\b[a-zа-яё]\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)
```

[См. демо](https://ideone.com/mLLtRi)

Если ничего не помагает, используйте PCRE:

```
x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123"
gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}\\b"," ", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж      ZZ 123"
```

Ещё [одно демо](https://ideone.com/qMIGfd).

- `(*UCP)` - включает поддержку Юникода в регулярке
- `\\b`  - граница слова  (начало слова)
- `\\p{L}` - любая буква Юникода
- `\\b` - граница слова (конец слова)

Comment: Очень странно. Ваш же пример запускаю у себя:  `gsub(pattern = "\\b[a-zа-яё]\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)` получаю `" - 1 ,   ковый оцинкованный ё       ZZ 123"`

Comment: Видимо в этом дело: sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
locale:
LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  
LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251
LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251

Comment: Да, всё дело в настройках. Попробуйте `gsub("\\b[[:alpha:]]\\b"," ", \`Encoding<-\`(x, "UTF8"),ignore.case = T)` или смените  `LC_COLLATE` на `English_United States.1252` или `LC_ALL`.

Comment: А разве PCRE не сработает также, как ICU? `gsub("(*UCP)\\b\\p{L}\\b"," ", x, perl=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработало так.

```
> gsub(pattern = "\\b[a-zа-яё]\\b",replacement = " ",x = " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж я  z ZZ 123",ignore.case = T)
[1] " - 1 , очковый оцинкованный ёж      ZZ 123"

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RDocumentation_0.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1          rjson_0.2.15       
 [3] R6_2.2.0            tools_3.3.2        
 [5] withr_1.0.2         curl_2.3           
 [7] githubinstall_0.2.1 memoise_1.0.0      
 [9] data.table_1.10.0   jsonlite_1.2       
[11] digest_0.6.11       proto_1.0.0
```